# Weird top bar duplication

Tags: 18.04, gui, hdmi, top-bar

When I connect my HDMI along with my second monitor and built in display, I get this from my top bar, a weird two-row duplication.

[image]

How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Maybe it can help understanding the problem, if you tell us about the graphics card/chip (brand name and model) and the graphics driver that is running.

Comment: Is this also happening in FireFox/Chromium or only Chrome?  and what's the output to `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 vga`?

Comment: gaj@gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 [8086:1616] (rev 09)
 Subsystem: Lenovo HD Graphics 5500 [17aa:3824]
 Kernel driver in use: i915

Comment: happens on the OS level

Comment: @Mookey Submit a bug report. This is likely a bug in how HiDPI handling is done, and something GNOME developers + Ubuntu developers should know about and  fix.

Answer (score 0):

It's in fact a weird problem. And maybe you should try to open a bug ticket to the Ubuntu Developers. Despite that, this what I would try:

I've solve many issues regarding Ubuntu using Gnome's Shell Extensions, this is one you should try:

[Monitors Add-On](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/921/multi-monitors-add-on/)

If that doesn't work, you might consider upgrade your version to 18.10.

Good luck.